# Как возвести 0.5 в третью степень

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, java, javascript

Как возвести 0.5 в третью степень не при помощи встроенных методов, а руками?
(0.5\cdot 0.5\cdot 0.5)!==0.125 ,а равно ноль. Как сделать правильно?

Comment: Вы че совсем что ли? (.5 * .5 * .5) компьютер пока что не способен догадываться!

Comment: я целый час сидел в недоумении, потом решил - всё, хватит, и спросил тут. А потом посмотрел и оказалось, что я забыл об изменении имени переменной и проверял не ту. Спасибо!

Comment: спать нужно вовремя ложиться.

Comment: js: Math.pow(0.5,3)

Comment: Если не указывать тип переменной то она воспринимается как целое, то есть 0.5 интерпретируется как 0, оттуда и ноль в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический метод pow() класса Math:

```
// Вычисляет и возвращает base, возведенное в степень pow.
Math.pow(base:Number, pow:Number):Number
```

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#pow()

Answer (score 1):

```
    double t = 0.5*0.5*0.5;
    System.out.println(t);
```

так выводит 0.125